# Ошибка "Performing stop of activity that is not resumed"

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 2 `Activity`:

1. `LoginActivity`
2. `MainActivity`

`LoginActivity` в `manifest` прописан как главный:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

В методе `onCreate()` `MyApplication` я проверяю базу, если я авторизован, то перехожу к `MainActivity` иначе ничего, то есть автоматически запустится `LoginActivity`:

```
private void startActivity(){
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    AccessDataModel accessDM = realm.where(AccessDataModel.class).findFirst();
    AccessDataModel accessDataModel;

    if (accessDM != null) {
        accessDataModel = realm.copyFromRealm(accessDM);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    realm.close();
}
```

Так вот, и так и так `LoginActivity` запускается. И поэтому если я авторизован, то перехожу к `MainActivity`, а `LoginActivity` запускается на фоне, и когда нажимаю назад в `MainActivity`, закрывается, и вижу активный `LoginActivity`.

Я думаю поэтому получаю эту ошибку:

> Performing stop of activity that is not resumed

**Вопросы:**

1. Как быть в этом случается?
2. Правильна ли логика в `MyApplication`?
3. Как избавиться от этой ошибки?

Comment: ну если условие срабатывает и вызывается MainActivity то под интентом может закрывать LoginActivity вызвав finish();?

Comment: Проверять авторизацию в методе Application.onCreate не лучшая идея, т.к он не обязательно вызывается перед стартом какой то активности. Например если приложение не запущено и сработал какой то ресивер/сервис и т.д то onCreate будет вызван в результате чего запуститься какая то активность, чего пользователь естественно не ожидает. Проверяйте флаг авторизации например в LoginActivity

Comment: @temq, тоже так думал. Если делать проверку в `LoginActivity`, то `MainActivity` запускается чуть дольше чем через `MyApplication`, можно ли это как то исправить?

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы по клику "назад" не открывалась активити логина, добавь этот код в MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```